# which muscles are more attractive and should i focus on

Tags: muscle

I see woman with  swimwear and I am attracted by them. I wonder if a man with swimwear with abs,chest,biceps and more if is attracted to the most women. Example the most of us if we see a woman which is tall,she is little fatter and she has nice body we say she is amazing. For men especially for muscles guys this happens too or the women doesn't care about the muscle a man has? If a women attracted by muscles which muscles should I give emphasis? I am not workout only about women but I care and about this :) I want to be more attracted to them. thanks In advance :)

Comment: Attractiveness is subjective. Case closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking will larger muscles and in particular which muscles will make me more attractive to women? This is not really the type of question for this site, as it's so much about opinion. However in my experience, for most woman, yes larger muscles do make men more attractive. But it's a scale and most don't like too much muscle and prefer a more athletic look.

In terms of making this your goal - I don't think you should concentrate on one area - instead focus on building overall strength and size.